# Inserting to sqlite db from different Activities Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
  final SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("phone_calls",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
  mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Numbers(PhoneNumber VARCHAR,FullName     VARCHAR,Cost VARCHAR );");
 mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Calls(FromNum VARCHAR,ToNum     VARCHAR,duration VARCHAR );");
```

Ive created this sqlite in Activity 1. i inserted some data to the first table in first activity.

now i created a second activity and i want to insert data to the other table?what shall i do? create the database again in the second activity and insert in it? or is there any other way?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/ try this

Comment: Leaving a raw database object around isn't the preferred way to do it, but you won't be creating the database again. The method is called `openOrCreateDatabase` for a reason

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read the docs - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Next, you should try to write simple application in order to use new knowledge.

If it fails, then post the question with more code *and* Logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a database helper class which will create all your tables,
then create needed methods like saveObject(YourObject), deleteObject(id),
etc...

Make your helper singleton and initiate it once in Application in onCreate()

and just use it in your activities.

For example you can look here: https://gist.github.com/mikeplate/9173040

Comment: ive created the database without using the database helper. all what i want to access this database in another activity. should i also in this case create the database helper class?